# how to find which procedures are performing insert/update operations from a package which has 100s of them in oracle

Tags: oracle

how to find which procedures are performing insert/update operations from a package which has 100s of them in oracle?

I tried the below query but it only gives the names of the packages not the specific procs calling them.

```
SELECT distinct(NAME) FROM USER_source 
WHERE TYPE in ('PACKAGE BODY') and UPPER(text) LIKE '%UPDATE %'
```

Comment: So, you want the name of the procedures that call the packages that have the update statements or to find out the name of the specific procedure name inside the package that has update statements?

Comment: Are you monitoring the process (such as a batch job) and you want to know which procedure is issuing the active insert/update operations that you're seeing? If so then `program_id` in `v$sql` joins to `all_objects.object_id` to tell you the package name, and you can work out the procedure name from `program_line#` though there is no built-in function to do this so you'll have to write one.

Comment: Kaushik Nayak: To find out the name of specific procedure names inside a package that has update statements.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
select * from user_procedures upp
join user_source uss on uss.name = upp.object_name
where 
upper(text) like '%UPDATE%'
;
```

Comment: That might be a start, although the text `UPDATE` might be part of a comment or some unrelated object name. Also `user_procedures` doesn't show private subprograms defined within package bodies.